# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' for DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my application I use the following code to retrieve fields of a collection of a document from Firebase Firestore Database:

```
var animalList = <Animal>[];
  documents.forEach((d) {
    animalList.add(Animal(
        d.data()['animal']['name'],
        d.data()['animal']['weight']));
  });
```

The document in the database looks like this:

[image]

I get the error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'". But this code already worked in the past with older Firebase versions.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show your log response and what documents actually is?

Comment: I edited the part from the database.

Comment: I mean, in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

```
var animalList = <Animal>[];
  documents.forEach((d) {
    animalList.add(Animal(
       d['animal']['name'],
       d['animal']['weight']));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

add `AsyncSnapshot` before variable `d`

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: ...,
  builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot d) {
  ....
  }
);
```